# why we use clrscr() function after declaration in c?

Tags: c, function

First snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a;
    clrscr();
}
```

Second Snippet

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a;
}
```

Which one is correct?

First or second?

Comment: This question would be more "correct" if you omit the `#include` so that it is obviously a _fragment_ and not intended to be complete - because as it is you have not included a declaration of `clrscr()`.  "we" don't use `clrcsr()` - you do in this code; the specific function called is irrelevant to the question.  The question is not well formed because in this case `a` is unused so need not be there at all.

Comment: You should include  '#include<conio.h>' to use clrscr() function.

Comment: 1) The second form is only valid in C11.   2) I don't know why you should be calling clrscr() at all.  Maybe if you explained more about the context.  Maybe "int a" is just a proxy for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Correct as in standard compliant? None of both. `main()` shall return `int` and when you want to express that a function takes no parameters, the parameter list should be `void`:

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

Other signatures are implementation-defined.

`clrscr()` is no function that is required to be declared in `<stdio.h>` by the standard. Also, variables are no longer required to be declared on the begin of a block since C99. They should be declared as close as possible to where they're used.

Comment: Note that `main` might be defined in an implementation-defined manner, so `void main()` can be fine in some environments. But, of course, one should use the standard way unless there is a good reason.

Comment: but what is c99?

Comment: @NishantPatel [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#C99). Here is a draft of the language standard for C99: [ISO/IEC 9899:TC3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)

Comment: @NishantPatel:  C99 refers to the revision of the ISO language standard that was ratified in 1999.  The first official standard was ratified in 1989, so that version is referred to as C89.  The version of the language prior to 1988 is often referred to as K&R C.  The most recent revision was ratified in 2011, so you’ll see people talk about C11 or C201.

Comment: @JohnBode *The most recent revision was ratified in 2011* – C18 was published in June 2018.

Comment: @JohnBode for clarity (or not) C89 refers to ANSI C.  ISO adopted that standard in 1990, so you also see C90 referred to, though it is the same as C89. I generally prefer to be explicit and reference "ISO C90".

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` is unused in the function call, the order is irrelevant.  Both statements are entirely independent of each other.

You will see a great deal of code where *all* variables are declared at the start of a block because that was required prior to ISO C99 and either old habits die hard, or good code lasts longer than the compiler originally used to build it.  If you are maintaining a legacy system and must use an old compiler, then you may need  to conform to this.

A great deal of code you will see will have all declarations at the start of the *function* rather then localised in blocks.  This was never necessary, but it was a common practice or misconception.

The ability to declare variables at any point in a block was introduced to C++ and adopted by C in ISO C99.  It is generally considered good practice to localise variables as much as possible, so declare them as late as possible in the outer-most scope in which they are used.

In your example, the variable `a` is not in fact used at all so "best practice" would be to remove it altogether, making both examples identical - in that sense your question is a poor illustration of either option as it does not illustrate the benefits of either practice.